# Error: Main method not found in class in codio

Tags: java, swing, oop, codio

Hi im still a student learning Java. Im supposed to make this calculator but im having an error and I don't know how to fix it.

here are my codes:

```
**import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class Task1 extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
   JLabel label1,label2;
   JTextField textField1,textField2; 
   JButton button1,button2,button3,button4,button5,button6;
   double addResult=0;
   double subResult=0;
   double mulResult=0;
   double divResult=0;

   public void Task1()    
   {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2,5,5)); 
      
    label1=new JLabel("First Value: "); 
    add(label1);
    textField1=new JTextField(10); 
    add(textField1);
    label2=new JLabel("Second Value"); 
    add(label2);
    textField2=new JTextField(10); 
    add(textField2);
    button1=new JButton("ADD"); 
    add(button1);
    button1.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    button1.addActionListener(this); 
    button2=new JButton("SUBSTRACT"); 
    add(button2);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    button3=new JButton("MULTIPLY"); 
    add(button3);
    button3.addActionListener(this);
    button4=new JButton("DIVIDE"); 
    add(button4);
    button4.addActionListener(this);
    button5=new JButton("COMPUTE"); 
    add(button5);
    button5.addActionListener(this);
    button6=new JButton("RESET"); 
    add(button6);
    button6.addActionListener(this);
      
      
  }
 @Override
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)
 {
   try{
    if(evt.getSource()==button1) 
    {
    String text=textField1.getText(); 
    String text2=textField2.getText();
    if(text.equals("")||text2.equals("")) 
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter Values"); 
  }
    addResult=addResult+Integer.parseInt(text)+Integer.parseInt(text2); 
  }
    if(evt.getSource()==button2) 
  {
    String text=textField1.getText(); 
    String text2=textField2.getText();
    if(text.equals("")||text2.equals(""))
  {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter Values"); 
  }
    subResult=subResult+(Integer.parseInt(text)-Integer.parseInt(text2)); 
  }
    if(evt.getSource()==button3) 
  {
    String text=textField1.getText();
    String text2=textField2.getText(); 
    if(text.equals("")||text2.equals("")) 
  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter Values"); 
  }
     mulResult=mulResult+(Integer.parseInt(text)*Integer.parseInt(text2)); 
  }
     if(evt.getSource()==button4) 
  {
     String text=textField1.getText(); 
     String text2=textField2.getText();
     if(text.equals("")||text2.equals("")) 
  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please Enter Values"); 
  }
     divResult=divResult+(Integer.parseInt(text)/Integer.parseInt(text2)); 
  }
     if(evt.getSource()==button5) 
  {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Result: "+ 
  (addResult+subResult+mulResult+divResult));
  }
     if(evt.getSource()==button6) 
 {
     textField1.setText(""); 
     textField2.setText("");
  }
  
  }
     catch(Exception e)
 {
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Exception: "+e.getMessage()); 
 }
}
}**
```

and here's the error:

Error: Main method not found in class Task1, please define the main method as:
public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
codio@border-florida:~/workspace/swing$

Comment: *"I don't know how to fix it."* Well, what do you understand from the error reported? Do some searching, SO is not a place to come to have (the meaning of) basic errors explained.

Comment: Read the [Swing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. All section have working demos you can download and they all show how to write a main() method for your class.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error text you will need to specify a `main` method. A `main` method is the starting point for all java applications. You should have gotten some material from school where this is explained. Search for a method named `main` there or look it up in Oracles basic Java tutorials.

Moreover you will have to do some more work to actually see this `JPanel` named `Task1`, but your school material or the basic swing tutorials linked by other replies explain these things.

Answer (score -4):

First, You should put you class in a package.
Second, you have to override the method `start` like this :

```java
@Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
         //put your starting code here
    }
```

Comment: (1-) this is not a JavaFX question. This suggestion would only confuse the OP.